# I'm not prompted for username/password in Edge Chromium so I get a 401 Unauthorised

Tags: microsoft-edge

This was working fine in Chrome but recently I switched to the Chromium based Edge.

When I browse to my TFS site, I get:

```
Error
The page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.
 More information about this error
Things you can try:
Refresh the current page
Go back to the previous page
Sign in as a different user
Submit feedback to Microsoft about this error
```

If I click Sign in as a different user, it thinks about it then I get the generic IIS 401 Unauthorized page with no prompt.

Chrome would normally prompt me for credentials.

Is there a way to force it to prompt me? Or another fix?

Comment: Sounds like your Edge may have NTLM and/or Kerberos disabled by Group Policy.

Comment: Is this on a work-owned computer? A company web site? If so you need to ask your IT folks about this.